# Floating garbage collector

Tags: water, buoyancy

I am trying to build a floating garbage collector. The concept isn't that hard, but when it comes to the math and physics it's beyond me. The idea is a floating bin that allows the garbage to fall into it because it's right above the water. Underneath it there's a water pump that evacuates the water fallen into it. How can I calculate so that my bin will always remain at a certain level of sinking in the water, even after garbage falls into it?

Comment: "*The idea is a floating bin that allows the garbage to fall into it because it's right above the water.*" It reads like you expect things to fall uphill.

Comment: I don't know how to put it better into words. It's practically a floating bin that allows garbage to fall in it due to its position on water (because the water also falls in it) while under the bin there's a pomp that allows the water to evacuate from the bin.

Comment: @DKNguyen For floatation some part would need to remain above water, not necessarily the inlet.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically describing a swimming pool leaf filter, except that they are usually attached or built in to the side of the pool. If you want it free floating where the inlet is slightly below the waterline so water and trash flows into the inlet, passes through a catch basket, and then water is  pumped out at the bottom you can put floats above the inlet and ballast weights at the bottom. The amount of floatation and its  height above the inlet can be set to match the buoyancy and inlet depth you want. The amount of ballast, if needed, just needs to be enough to keep it stable and upright as it floats.